# Using -notcontains to find substring within string within array

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to avoid using nested ForEach Loop as part of a larger code. To do this, I'm using the -notcontains operator. Basically, I want to see if a substring exists within a string within an array. If it exists, do nothing, if it does not exist, print "Not Found".

Here is the code...

```
$arr = @('"value11","value21","value31"','"value12","value22","value32"','"value13","value23","value33"')

if ($arr -notcontains "*`"value24`"*")
{
    Write-Host "Not Found"
}

if ($arr -notcontains "*`"value22`"*")
{
    Write-Host "Not Found 2"
}
```

We can see that value24 is not within any strings of the array. However, value22 is within the 2nd string in the array.

Therefor the results should output the following...

```
Not Found
```

However, instead I see the following output...

```
Not Found
Not Found 2
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: FYI, Looks like the contains operator requires an exact match of the item within the array, and wildcards are useless - http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_conditional_operators.htm. I have an answer brewing shortly, and it's definitely not the cleanest solution. If someone has a better solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: Do you want to react to each match/notmatch or just if it is present in the array period?

Comment: basically if the substring does not exist within any string of the array, it should only print "Not Found" once. If it does exist within the array, don't print anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on a solution:

```
($arr | foreach {$_.contains('"value24"')}) -contains $true
```

Using the V3 .foreach() method:

```
($arr.ForEach({$_.contains('"value24"')}).contains($true))
```

And yet another possibility:

```
[bool]($arr.where({$_.contains('"value24"')}))
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but look closer, it's a (confusing) array of strings, where the strings are single quotes and then contain what looks like an array of double quoted strings. Unless it's so confusing that I'm reading it wrong too..

Comment: You're right. It's actually more of a substring search.  But the solution still appears to work.

Comment: Ah perfect. I just had to change `-contains` to `-notcontains`. But this is exactly what I'm looking for... Thanks :D

Comment: I saw the comment about not using the pipeline (appears to have been deleted now, so I'm not sure what that was about), but if it's a problem then no worries.  You're using V3, so you also have the option of using the .foreach() method of $arr. Update the answer with an example.

Comment: The issue was I was passing a variable `$_.USR_ID` from the previous pipeline. I was still able to use your line of code, I just had to add a line (prior to your line) `$searchValue = $_.USR_ID`. Then change `If (($resultsFileContents | foreach {$_.contains($_.USR_ID)}) -notcontains $true)` to `If (($resultsFileContents | foreach {$_.contains($searchValue)}) -notcontains $true)`. I didn't feel this was worth mentioning though, since it was not related to the original question. Apologies for the previous comment I removed.

Comment: just an fyi, I get an error with v3 on that 2nd line `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'ForEach'.`

Answer (score 3):

`-contains` and `-notcontains` don't operate against patterns.

Luckily, `-match` and `-like` and their negative counterparts, when used with an array on the left side, return an array of the items that satisfy the condition:

```
'apple','ape','vape' -like '*ape'
```

Returns:

> ```
> ape
> vape
> ```

In an `if` statement, this still works (a 0 count result will be interpreted as `$false`):

```
$arr = @('"value11","value21","value31"','"value12","value22","value32"','"value13","value23","value33"')

if ($arr -notlike "*`"value24`"*")
{
    Write-Host "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: Well there goes my answer draft :)

Comment: @Matt haha you usually beat me I think

Comment: the problem with this, if you change that `value24` in the if statement to `value22`, it will still say `"Not Found"`. I believe using the -like or the -match does not check each item individually. See my complicated answer for correct results...

Comment: ``"*`"value24`"*"`` should just be `'*"value24"*'` no escaping.

Comment: nope, it returns `"Not Found"` if I change that value in the if statement to `'*"value22"*'`. Instead, it should not print anything.

Comment: @FiddleFreak That was not meant to address you current issue. Just the code.

Comment: @FiddleFreak _does not check each item individually_? What is your expected output. Your test above appears to just be overall?

Comment: Updated 2nd sentence in question. Also, please see my answer below (Note: it should only print "Not Found" once, not for every string in the array)...

Answer (score 0):

## Edit for clearer answer on what I'm looking for...

This is the only way I'm able to figure this out so far. I hope there is a much cleaner solution...

```
$arr = @('"value11","value21","value31"','"value12","value22","value32"','"value13","value23","value33"')

$itemNotFound = $true
ForEach ($item in $arr)
{
    If ($itemNotFound)
    {
        If ($item -like "*`"value24`"*")
        {
            $itemNotFound = $false
        }
    }

}
if ($itemNotFound)
{
    Write-Host "Not Found value24"
}


$itemNotFound = $true
ForEach ($item in $arr)
{
    If ($itemNotFound)
    {
        If ($item -like "*`"value22`"*")
        {
            $itemNotFound = $false
        }
    }

}
if ($itemNotFound)
{
    Write-Host "Not Found value22"
}
```

## output will be:

```
Not Found value24
```